# Bootstrap - div is below others, how to bring above

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if there's been another question about this one, but I'm totally lost.
I'm working on this design based on Bootstrap and one of my div's just can't seem to go above the rest.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122550/diylab/index.html

The yellow div to the side with '10 year warranty' etc goes under the image (and text if browser is not very high) above 'Save thousands' when the screen is at that size.

How can I get that div to go above the others? Sorry for the n00b question :)

Comment: phil answer will solve the problem, but i recommend to increase the number from 1 to like 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
z-index: 1;
```

to your `.happy` CSS rule seems to do the job